# Glassfish [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8.1

I'm having a trouble adding resources to glassfish. I'm working with Java Message Dreven Beans and Hibernate. My problem is less the code and more glassfish (i've not depoyed any projects yet, still I can't do the firsts steps in admin tool).

Im using Netbeans 8.1 and glassfish 4.1.1 newlly installed from netbeans.com

[image: Image one]
[image]

Here's the server log:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event152'.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event152'.
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:551)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor149.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jsftemplating.handlers.UtilHandlers.mapPut(UtilHandlers.java:314)
... 51 more
```

Comment: I downgraded To 4.1 instead of 4.1.1. Then everything worked out just fine.

Comment: Having the same problem, wonder if they actually have done any unit tests before releasing the software?

Answer (score 4):

I see you downgraded to 4.1. I too had the same problem with resource creation with 4.1.1. There seems to be a bug in GLASSFISH that is not fixed yet.

Anyway, if you cannot create resources from the web admin console (which happens in 4.1.1) you can always create resources from asadmin console (in your glassfish folder).

Look at the examples here for jdbc:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ggndp/index.html

and here for JMS:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ablkb.html

It is really easy, try it out. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It's 2017 now and the problem remains in Glassfish 4.1.1.

But **Glassfish 4.1.2** seems to be working fine, allowing the creation of new JMS *Connection Factories* and *Destination Resources*.